# Comparing and updating excel columns in two different excel files

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file called "A" and it has two columns : "ID" and "quantity".
and i have another excel file called "B" and it also has two columns called "ID" (it has same values as File "A") and "quantity" (this quantity column has different values as File A quantity column)

so I want to update every cell in File "A" quantity column with File "B" Quantity column values

[File A and B at one glance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opqwD.png)

I want that after updating, File A "quantity" column and File B "quantity" column to be equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to replace values in an old file with the values in the new file.

Assuming the ID values don't repeat, you can just use an index + match to obtain the new values from the "B" file.

So replace the first value in column A with

> = INDEX ( [Select both columns in file B] ; MATCH ( [Select first value in ID column in file A] ; [Select ID column in file B] ; 0) ; 2)

(assuming Column B is the second column in file B)

And then copy that formula to all values in Column A.

Comment: Thanks For Helping me @marianomolina ,actually I'm very newbie in excel so I didn't understand what you said .There is 2 separate files : A and B . both files have 2 columns called ID and Quantity.what should I do ? changing ID column of File A with these Codes ? how can i refer to B file ?

Comment: Hi Ahmad. To reference a different spreadsheet you want to (1) have both files open, (2) open a formula (entre "=" in a cell) in file A and then, without clicking anywhere else, select the range you want to select in file B. With that in mind, you want to create this formula: = INDEX ( [Select both columns in file B] ; MATCH ( [Select first value in ID column in file A] ; [Select ID column in file B] ; 0) ; 2)